# Avoid socket disconnect when I reload the page

Tags: node.js, socket.io, angular9

I am developing an app with nodejs, socketio, angular9. The problem is when I reload the page the socket 'disconnect' in my node server is triggered.It is ok to trigger it when I close my page but not when I reload.How can I avoid disconnecting when reloading the page.

Comment: Its impossible. What next? Tomorrow you want keep connection up while you reset your computer? Day after you want to keep connection until you reincarnate?

Comment: Reload means that you close page. CLOSE. And then you open it again

Comment: I know one trick for task like that - you can open your page inside iframe, but socket in top level. Connection will be saved while you reloading content inside frame, but if you reload top level, connection will be broken

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, it is not possible to keep a socket connection alive through a refresh as you are effectively closing and then opening the site again.

If it is that you are storing user data for each socket connection, on the server, and don't want to lose it because of a refresh, you might want to look into keeping a cache of this data and using a connection heartbeat to determine when you can remove data from your cache. You would of course need to ID the user by something other than the socket connection.

Comment: Do you have a code example for this cache management ?